# Is there a way to implement a time delay on a single image?

Tags: python, tkinter, time

A small program that I'm working on using python is intended to display a series of images and audio clips in a certain order. I'm able to display two of the images in the same window, one overlaying the other as intended, but I'm looking for a way to make the second image appear after a certain amount of time (30 seconds) instead of as soon as the program is run. I cannot seem to get the second image called `textBox.jpg` to run separately from the rest of the program, though.

To try to resolve this problem, I put in the `sleep()` function, but that just delays the entire code from starting.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time

# Title/Main
window = Tk()
window.title("Just Monika")
window.configure(background="black")

# control window size to make full-screen
width_value=window.winfo_screenwidth()
height_value=window.winfo_screenheight()
window.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (width_value, height_value))

# Monika photo
# this block will allow the image to resize to fit the window's size
# indefinitely
def resize_image(event):
    new_width = event.width
    new_height = event.height
    image = copy_of_image.resize((new_width, new_height))
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    label.config(image = photo)
    label.image = photo #avoid garbage collection

monika = Image.open("C:\\Python Programs\\Just Monika\\Images\\justMonika.png")
copy_of_image = monika.copy()
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(monika)
label = ttk.Label(window, image = photo)
label.bind('<Configure>', resize_image)
label.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

# text box image
textBox = Image.open("C:\\Python Programs\\Just Monika\\Images\\textBox.jpg")
tkTextBox = ImageTk.PhotoImage(textBox)
panel1 = Label(window, image = tkTextBox)
panel1.place(x=675, y=300)
time.sleep(30)
```

I want the second image, `textBox.jpg`, to be called after the program has been running for about 30 seconds and the other image has already been displayed.

Comment: use tkinter `after()` function: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Masoud suggested, you can use the universal widget [`after()`](http://web.archive.org/web/20181025095013id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) method to schedule a function to be called after a specified time delay:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


PATH_IMAGE1 = 'justMonika.png'
PATH_IMAGE2 = 'textBox.png'
DELAY = 5000  # In milliseconds

# Title/Main
window = Tk()
window.title("Just Monika")
window.configure(background="black")

# control window size to make full-screen
width_value=window.winfo_screenwidth()
height_value=window.winfo_screenheight()
window.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (width_value, height_value))


# Monika photo
# this block will allow the image to resize to fit the window's size
# indefinitely
def resize_image(event):
    new_width = event.width
    new_height = event.height
    image = copy_of_image.resize((new_width, new_height))
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    label.config(image = photo)
    label.image = photo #avoid garbage collection

def display_2nd_image():
    global panel1

    # text box image
    textBox = Image.open(PATH_IMAGE2)
    tkTextBox = ImageTk.PhotoImage(textBox)
    panel1 = Label(window, image=tkTextBox)
    panel1.place(x=675, y=300)
    panel1.image = tkTextBox #avoid garbage collection

monika = Image.open(PATH_IMAGE1)
copy_of_image = monika.copy()
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(monika)
label = ttk.Label(window, image=photo)
label.bind('<Configure>', resize_image)
label.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

window.after(DELAY, display_2nd_image)
window.mainloop()
```